# Packaging A Docopt CLI Application

Tags: python, docopt

I want to package my Docopt app which consist of one class file and an other file which imports the class file and implements Docopt (https://gist.github.com/itsnauman/4d9e40459ff56106edcf). How should I package it so that I only enter the package's name `$ package_name --help` and it executes?

Comment: do you want to know how to use setuptools, or just the directory structure?

Comment: It will be appreciated if you tell me about both :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a `setup.py` file in the root folder of your project. It has to contain something in the line of:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "mypackage",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Description",
    packages = ["mypackage"],
    long_description = "",
    namespace_packages = ['mypackage'],
    scripts = ['scripts/script.py'] )
```

You could just include the docopt source in your `mypackage` folder, as docopt is not very long, and this will remove the dependency also.

The folder structure for this example should look like:

```
project-root/
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        myclass.py
    scripts/
        script.py
```

In `script.py` you would then do:

```
from mypackage import myclass
```

From the project root you can now run: `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop`.